# Edit default Pagelayout on feature activation

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, page-layout, feature-activation

My site is in SharePoint 2010.

I want to edit the content of `PageFromDocLayout.aspx` default page layout on feature activation. My feature is on site collection level.

I want to change the particular tag of `PageFromDocLayout.aspx`

Original tag value:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="400px" runat="server"/>
```

After the change in code:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" PrefixStyleSheet="my-rte" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="400px" runat="server"/>
```

is it possible to edit this specific tag dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to retrieve the file contents as string in your feature activation code:

```
    SPWeb web=(SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
    string fileUrl="/_catalogs/masterpage/PageFromDocLayout.aspx";
    string pageFromDocLayoutContent=web.GetFileAsString(fileUrl);
```

Then do some modification to the file contents as you wish. According to your example:

```
    string modifiedContent=pageFromDocLayoutContent.Replace("<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName=\"PublishingPageContent\" HasInitialFocus=\"True\" MinimumEditHeight=\"400px\" runat=\"server\"/>","<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName=\"PublishingPageContent\" PrefixStyleSheet=\"my-rte\" HasInitialFocus=\"True\" MinimumEditHeight=\"400px\" runat=\"server\"/>");
```

Then save the file to the web, overwriting the existing file. You can add some code to create a backup of the existing file somewhere first. Also, you will probably need to checkout the item first (if it is not already checked out).

```
    byte[] modifiedData=new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(modifiedContent);
    web.GetFile(fileUrl).CheckOut();
    web.Files.Add(fileUrl,modifiedData,true);
    web.GetFile(fileUrl).CheckIn("Modified During Feature Activation");
```

Do not forget to restore the backup on feature de activation!